# Run-time error '6': overflow on array that didn't used to be there

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have a data set that gets monitored 2 or 3 times per week and new data is added about that often as well. At the end of the month, it gets cleared and we start the process again.

The idea is that the vba handles the bulk of the logic monitoring, but some rows have to be manually tweaked. And that tweak needs to be kept as more data is added. What this part of the code is supposed to do is check if data has already been added, and if so, find it all and store in an array that some info (manually tweaked parts) can be placed back in later without having to do it by hand again.

The range of the array is large partly due to the organization of the data columns, partly due to using multiple columns as checks when placing info back into the sheet.

EDIT: updated with entire sub

NOTE: the called subs are pretty basic, just copying data from one place to another with a little built error handling for specific cases.

```
    Sub recon_data()
    Dim recon As Worksheet
    Set recon = Worksheets("Recon")
    Dim start_sheet As String
    Dim end_sheet As String
    start_sheet = "XXXXXX"
    end_sheet = "Recon"


    Call unfilter_sheet(end_sheet)

    Dim rw As Integer

    Dim altArray_exists As Boolean
    If Not IsEmpty(recon.Range("C8")) Then
        rw = recon.Range("C8").End(xlDown).Row
        Dim altArray() As Variant
        altArray = recon.Range("A8:Q" & rw).Value 'overflow error here
        recon.Range("A8:T" & rw).ClearContents
        altArray_exists = True
    Else
        altArray_exists = False
    End If

    Call copy_column(start_sheet, "B", end_sheet, "D") 
    Call copy_column(start_sheet, "C", end_sheet, "F") 
    Call copy_column(start_sheet, "D", end_sheet, "G") 
    Call name_extract(start_sheet, "O", end_sheet)      
    Call copy_column(start_sheet, "K", end_sheet, "J") 
    Call copy_column(start_sheet, "J", end_sheet, "K") 
    Call copy_column(start_sheet, "F", end_sheet, "L") 
    Call copy_column(start_sheet, "G", end_sheet, "M") 
    Call copy_column(start_sheet, "T", end_sheet, "N") 
    Call copy_column(start_sheet, "U", end_sheet, "O") 
    Call copy_column(start_sheet, "V", end_sheet, "P") 
    Call copy_column(start_sheet, "AA", end_sheet, "Q") 
    Call copy_column(start_sheet, "E", end_sheet, "C")
    Call final_number(end_sheet)

    rw = recon.Range("C8").End(xlDown).Row

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim finalArray
    If altArray_exists = True Then
       finalArray = recon.Range("A8:T" & rw).Value
        For i = LBound(finalArray) To UBound(finalArray) 
            For j = LBound(altArray) To UBound(altArray)
                If Not IsEmpty(altArray(j, 5)) Then
                    If altArray(j, 3) = finalArray(i, 3) _
                     And altArray(j, 13) = finalArray(i, 13) _
                     And altArray(j, 17) = finalArray(i, 17) Then 
                        finalArray(i, 5) = altArray(j, 5) 
                        finalArray(i, 1) = altArray(j, 1) 
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        recon.Range("A8:T" & rw).Value = finalArray
    End If

    recon.Range("G8:G" & rw).NumberFormat = "hh:mm am/pm" 
    recon.Range("Q8:Q" & rw).NumberFormat = "###.00" 

    End Sub
```

I only need the altArray if there is already data on the sheet, and altArray_exists just tells the vba if that array was created or not for other processes. Before someone questions my method of finding the last row in my dataset, it NEVER contains blank rows in this column, so xldown is fine for this. And C8 is my starting point because columns A & B are notes we add. Not always there, but must be kept if there is one.

The problem occurs when I'm trying to set altArray, where I get hit with the "run-time error '6': overflow". Error appeared this week after adding new data, not after I worked on any code. The last time I tested it with data from the month before, everything ran fine. If I delete everything and run the code like it's the beginning of the month, then it hits the "Else" of the if statement and runs the rest of the sub just fine.

Since I haven't messed with the code, the only thing that makes sense to me is a problem with the new data. But I don't understand how that would affect everything. What am I missing?

Comment: Integers are 16 bit signed so overflows after 32,767 rows.

Comment: @user14797724 Data tops out around 10,000 rows by the end of the month.

Comment: When it fails and you're in debug mode, paste `? recon.Range("C8").End(xlDown).Row` into the Immediate pane and hit Enter.  What's the output?

Comment: @TimWilliams There's no output in the immediate window because I get hit with the error. But when I add `rw` to the Locals window, it's 4353.

Comment: When you get the error you should be able to hit the Debug button and enter break mode: at that point you should be able to do what I suggested.

Comment: @TimWilliams Same thing, 4353

Comment: Works fine for me with some dummy data of similar size, so there's something else we're not seeing.  When it errors which line is highlighted?

Comment: @TimWilliams `altArray = recon.Range("A8:Q" & rw).Value`, all I know is that it all was working fine 2 weeks ago and now this. I haven't changed a single line of code in that time, and nobody else has access to it since it's just me testing it out right now.

Comment: Sorry I have no other suggestions unless you're able to share the data (or a redacted version with the same problem)

Comment: @TimWilliams I'll edit my post later with some more code, I'm doing 6 things at once right now. Check it this afternoon. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try making `rw` a long as it should be.

Comment: @user14797724 Same result, and again, the datasets only reach about 10,000 rows.